# How to cut off some part of element in css

Tags: html, css

In CSS, how can I make something like this:

[image]

```css
.my-btn {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 32px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<button class="my-btn">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i>
</button>
```

So far I made something like this:

[image]

But I don't know how to cut off that top-right edge.

Is this even possible?

PS. I made these images using by Photoshop, and in there I can easily use another path shape to subtract the main shape with it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask